# Laravel find records through intermediate table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 models:

- User
- Company
- Enquiry

A user can own more than one company, a company can only belong to one user. An enquiry can belong to many companies and a company can have many enquiries.

The migrations look as follows:

**User migration**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('contact_number');
            $table->longText('address')->nullable();
            $table->integer('postal_code');
            $table->string('activation_token')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('active')->default(false);
            $table->enum('type', ['Admin', 'End User', 'Service Provider', 'Broker']);
            $table->string('password')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

**Company Migration**

```
Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('service_provider_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('broker_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->string('contact_number');
            $table->longText('address')->nullable();
            $table->integer('postal_code');
            $table->enum('status', ['Confirmed', 'Declined', 'New'])->default('New');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });

        Schema::table('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('service_provider_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('broker_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
```

**Enquiries Migration**

```
Schema::create('enquiries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('end_user_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->integer('radius');
            $table->enum('status', ['New', 'In Progress', 'Complete'])->default('New');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('enquiries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('end_user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        });
```

**CompanyEnquiry Migration**

```
Schema::create('company_enquiry', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('enquiry_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('enquiry_id')->references('id')->on('enquiries')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->primary(['company_id', 'enquiry_id']);
        });
```

I have set up the various relationships in their respective models.

What I'm trying to achieve is query the database to retrieve only those enquiries which belong to the user via the company.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (add the real model, relation names ans columns):

```
$enquiries = Enquiries::whereHas(['companies' => function($query){
                $query->whereHas(['user' => function($query){
                     $query->where('id', $user_id);
                }]);
            })
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way with shorter code.

```
$enquiries = Enquiries::whereHas('companies.user', function($query) use($user_id){
       $query->where('id', $user_id);
 })->get();
```